# Trying to get a unique list of objects from an array in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, api, unique

Have an observable being returned from my service.ts as shown here:

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from 
'@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { PokeResponse } from '../PokeResponse';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
export class PokeApiService {

private url = "https://pokemon-go1.p.rapidapi.com/pokemon_stats.json";

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

getPokeData(): Observable<PokeResponse> {
  return this.http.get<PokeResponse>(this.url, 
  {
    headers : new HttpHeaders({
      'x-rapidapi-key': 'a6cef4cbcamsh05b29346394d4a4p1bafacjsn2a92406ac103'
    })
  })
.pipe(
  tap(data => console.log('Pokedata/Error' + JSON.stringify(data))
  ),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
}

private handleError(err:HttpErrorResponse) {
console.log('PokemonService: ' + err.message);
return Observable.throw(err.message);
}
}
```

This is my response:

```
export interface PokeResponse{
list:results[];

results:{
    pokemon_id:number;
    pokemon_name:string;
    base_attack:number;
    base_defense:number;
    base_stamina:number;
}[];
}
export interface results{
    pokemon_id:number;
    pokemon_name:string;
    base_attack:number;
    base_defense:number;
    base_stamina:number;
}

export class Pokemon implements results{

    pokemon_id:number;
    pokemon_name:string;
    base_attack:number;
    base_defense:number;
    base_stamina:number;

constructor(_id:number, _name:string, _atk:number, _def:number, _stam:number) {

    _id = this.pokemon_id;
    _name = this.pokemon_name;
    _atk = this.base_attack;
    _def = this.base_defense;
    _stam = this.base_stamina;
}
}
```

And this is my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PokeApiService } from 'src/app/services/poke-api.service';
import { PokeResponse, results, Pokemon } from 'src/app/PokeResponse';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-pokemon',
  templateUrl: './list-pokemon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-pokemon.component.css']
})
export class ListPokemonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private pokeService: PokeApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPokeDetails();
  }

  pokeData:PokeResponse;
  errorMessage:any;

 pokeArray:results;

  getPokeDetails() : boolean {
    this.pokeService.getPokeData().subscribe(
      pokeData => {
        this.pokeData=pokeData;
        console.table(pokeData);
      },
       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
    return false;
  }
}
```

In my console I'm getting back a console.table of my observable like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF0nb.png)

I'm trying to filter out the names of Pokemon which are the same as others, which could also be achieved by just filtering out any of the pokemon_ids as all the stats match regardless of the type.

So far I've tried:

`console.log(this.pokeArray);`,

using `[...Set()]`, `forEach()`, and `Array.from()`

Any help or suggestions on how I can make this question any clearer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code here as text instead of images.

Comment: Ok changed it @Phix

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [groupBy](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/groupby) operator in rxjs to group the pokémon by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using filter:

```
// list-pokemon.component.ts
export class ListPokemonComponent implements OnInit {
  uniqueListPoke = [];
  flags = {};

  constructor(private pokeService: PokeApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPokeDetails();
  }

  pokeData:PokeResponse;
  errorMessage:any;

 pokeArray:results;

  getPokeDetails() : boolean {
    this.pokeService.getPokeData().subscribe(
      pokeData => {
        this.uniqueListPoke = pokeData.filter((entry) => {
            if (this.flags[entry.pokemon_name]) {
              // console.log('flags', false);
                return false;
            }
            this.flags[entry.pokemon_name] = true;
            return true;
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.uniqueListPoke));
      },
       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
    return false;
  }
}
```

The working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-distinct-poke?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Worked a charm, I have a red line under filter for some reason but it still seems to work fine thanks a million